# How can I keep image url after form postback using asp.net core mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

The problem I am facing now is the fileupload input tags which gives "No file chosen" after failed ModelState validation and I have to choose the image file again, so how to keep the chosen file image even after postback?

```
 <div id="imagediv" class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
            <img id="img1" class="img-rounded" />
            <input type="file" name="myfile" id="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" class="form-control-file" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
            <input asp-for="Image" id="fileinput" class="form-control" />
        </div>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#file").change(function () {
            if ($("#file").val() != "") {
                $("#fileinput").prop("value", $("#file").val().split('\\').pop());

                //to show new image at a time of image selected from file input type
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) { $('#img1').attr('src', e.target.result); }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
       </script>
```

Comment: You could convert the image to be base64 string

Comment: I dont have issue with uploading to server, All I want it to retain the image path on view page.

Comment: you server could respond with a base64 that represents the image and then show the image with `<img src='data:image/gif;base64,xxxxxxxxxx'>`

Comment: I didnt get a solution  to this question yet, what shall I do ?

Comment: There're quite a lot of ways to do that. One approach is to upload your image with ajax , and dynamically set the image with `src=uploaded_uri`, so you needn't upload a second time; Another approach is to encode your image as base64 string so that you could pass the base64 string between browser and server back and forth(e.g.:  add a hidden input and set the value=base64 ). Both should work.

Comment: Can you clarify each step and add it as an answer please, so I can flag it as proper answer to my problem. Thank you itminus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large files, I would suggest you should upload the image on server by ajax and set the url dynamically. But I'm not aware of how your server serves static images. So I'll show you an easy way to pass image as base64 string back and forth. This way is rather simple for small size files.

Assuming your view model is :

```
public class MyViewModel{
    [MinLength(6)]
    public string Image {get;set;}
    public string DataUrl{get;set;}    
    // ... other fields as you like
}
```

and change your form as below:

```
<form method="post" action="/home/index2" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" class="form-control-file" />

    <!--file name-->
    <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Image" id="fileinput" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>

    <!-- preview -->
    <img id="img1" src="@Model.DataUrl" alt="your-image" class="img-rounded" />
    <input name="DataUrl" type="hidden" value="@Model.DataUrl">

    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note I create a hidden `DataUrl` to hold the base64 encoded string as url. When the file changes, we need set the value of DataUrl:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#file").change(function () {
            if ($("#file").val() != "") {
                $("#fileinput").prop("value", $("#file").val().split('\\').pop());
                //to show new image at a time of image selected from file input type
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) { 
                        $('#img1').attr('src', e.target.result); 
                        $('input[name="DataUrl"]').val(e.target.result);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

and the action method looks like:

```
    [HttpPost("/home/index2")]
    public IActionResult Index(MyViewModel vm, IFormFile myfile)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid){
            // ...
        }else{
            // ...
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
```

demo :

[image]